# How can I set default page to the last page when using pagination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

Assuming there are 115 communities.
Then it show 10 communities per page with pagination.

When I'm going to `example.com/communities`, it shows 10 oldest records.

However, I want it to link to  `example.com/communities?page=12` as default.
It should be linked to the last page of communities.

Is it possible?

Now my link is just like this

```
<%= link_to "Communities", communities_path %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible but you have to add some logic

```
communities = Community.page(params[:page])
communities.total_pages # 12
communities_path(page: communities.total_pages)
```

or you can just reverse the ordering of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of thinking about it. Change your order by so it shows the newest.

So on your arel query, do something like this:

```
Blog.all.order("id desc")
```

I left the pagination call out as i do not know what pagination library you are using :).